# Can't locate loadable object for module Math:: Pari in @INC

Tags: perl, ssh, cpan, pari

I've written a Perl script which runs fine on my environment, but on my client environment it fails on:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Math::Pari in @INC (@INC contains: Error-0.17020/lib        JSON-2.57/lib URI-1.60 libwww-perl-5.836/lib Net-Address-IP-Local-0.1.2/lib Math-GMP-2.06/ Net-     SSH-Perl-1.35/lib/ /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2  /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl  .) at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Util/SSH2MP.pm line 6
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Util/SSH2MP.pm line 6,  <GEN0> line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Util/SSH2MP.pm line  6,  <GEN0> line 1.
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Util.pm line 56, <GEN0>  line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Kex/DH1.pm line 10,  <GEN0> line 1.
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Kex.pm line 6, <GEN0>  line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Kex.pm line 6,  <GEN0> line 1.
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/SSH2.pm line 6, <GEN0>  line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/SSH2.pm line 6,  <GEN0> line 1.
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl.pm line 52, <GEN0> line   1.
the user: ll was successfully added to the automation machine.notroot@ubuntu:~/autom    ation$ vim install.pl
```

I've tried to add
use lib 'Math';
with the contains the content of Math-Pari-2.0305_01080605 module, but no luck:/

I don't want my client to install cpan packages from by him self - it should be fully environment independent product.

I prefer to avoid switching from "Net-SSH-Perl-1.35" since large parts of my code depends on it.

My starting point was with the following libraries:

```
use lib 'Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib/'; 
use lib 'Math-GMP-2.06/'; 
use lib 'Net-Address-IP-Local-0.1.2/lib';
use lib 'libwww-perl-5.836/lib';
use lib 'URI-1.60';
use lib 'JSON-2.57/lib';
use lib 'Error-0.17020/lib';
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use LWP::Simple;
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use POSIX qw/strftime/;
use Net::Address::IP::Local;
```

Which output the following:

```
Can't locate Math/Pari.pm in @INC (@INC contains: Error-0.17020/lib JSON-2.57/lib URI-1.60 libwww-  perl-5.836/lib Net-Address-IP-Local-0.1.2/lib Math-GMP-2.06/ Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib/ /etc/perl    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5     /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at Net-SSH-Perl-  1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Util/SSH2MP.pm line 6, <GEN0> line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Util/SSH2MP.pm line 6,  <GEN0> line 1.
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Util.pm line 56, <GEN0> line   1.
 BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Kex/DH1.pm line 10  ,  <GEN0> line 1.
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Kex.pm line 6, <GEN0> line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Kex.pm line 6, <GEN0> line 1.
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/SSH2.pm line 6, <GEN0> line 1  .
```

BEGIN failed – compilation aborted...

In order to fix that I've added the next statement:

Use lib 'Math-Pari-2.010709';

And the error changed to:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Math::Pari in @INC (@INC contains: Math-Pari-2.010709 Error- 0.17020/lib JSON-2.57/lib URI-1.60 libwww-perl-5.836/lib Net-Address-IP-Local-0.1.2/lib Math-GMP-2.06/  Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib/ /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5  /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at Net-SSH-Perl- 1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Util/SSH2MP.pm line 6
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Util/SSH2MP.pm line 6, <GEN0> line   1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Util/SSH2MP.pm line 6, <GEN0>  line 1.
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Util.pm line 56, <GEN0> line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Kex/DH1.pm line 10, <GEN0>  line 1.
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Kex.pm line 6, <GEN0> line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib//Net/SSH/Perl/Kex.pm line 6, <GEN0> line 1.
Compilation failed in require at Net-SSH-Perl-1....
```

This is the content of Math-Pari-2.010709:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 notroot notroot 4096 May  7 14:38 ./
drwxr-xr-x 11 notroot notroot 4096 May  7 21:30 ../
drwxr-xr-x  7 notroot notroot 4096 May  7 14:38 Math/
```

Math-Pari-2.010709/Math:

```
total 240
drwxr-xr-x 7 notroot notroot  4096 May  7 14:38 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 notroot notroot  4096 May  7 14:38 ../ 
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot 27440 Oct 25  2006 Changes
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot 17793 Feb  1  2004 func_codes.h
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot  8676 Aug  9  2006 INSTALL 
drwxr-xr-x 2 notroot notroot  4096 Oct 25  2006 libPARI/
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot  7573 Oct 25  2006 Makefile.PL
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot   780 Nov 11  2005 MANIFEST
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot   297 Oct 25  2006 META.yml
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot  1322 Aug 23  2006 PariInit.pm
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot 35680 Oct 25  2006 Pari.pm
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot 79499 Oct 18  2006 Pari.xs
drwxr-xr-x 2 notroot notroot  4096 Oct 25  2006 patches/
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot  4286 Jan 30  2004 README
drwxr-xr-x 2 notroot notroot  4096 Oct 25  2006 t/
drwxr-xr-x 2 notroot notroot  4096 Oct 25  2006 test_eng/
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot  1142 Jan 20  2005 TODO
-r--r--r-- 1 notroot notroot  1361 Jul  8  2001 typemap
drwxr-xr-x 3 notroot notroot  4096 Oct 25  2006 utils/
```

I need to say that the folder Math didn't originally exist at Math-Pari-2.010709, so I've created it and moved Math-Pari-2.010709 content into it in order location Perl was looking for.

In this stage I've added:
use Math:: Pari

But it seems that doesn't make a difference:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Math::Pari in @INC (@INC contains: Math-Pari-2.010709 Error- 0.17020/lib JSON-2.57/lib URI-1.60 libwww-perl-5.836/lib Net-Address-IP-Local-0.1.2/lib Math-GMP-2.06/    Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib/ /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5  /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./install.pl  line 24
Compilation failed in require at ./install.pl line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./install.pl line 24.
```

I thing that summarize all my attempts so far.

Comment: Shouldn't you do something like 'use Pari;' after your 'use lib' statement? Check the documentation of 'use'

Comment: You should show your `use` statements. Are you giving the full path in your `use lib`?

Comment: so your `perl` script is sitting at the root of all these paths? Otherwise, you need to add full paths to these.

Comment: @chrsblck, the script is indeed at the root of all these paths

Comment: I don't see `use Math::Pari` in your "UPDATE". Also, I don't see the `Math-Pari-2.010709` path in your `@INC` error. Can you confirm this path is correct?

Comment: Once you address @chrsblck's concerns, can you show us the contents of Math-Pari-2.010709 on the client machine?  Perhaps your environment has `Math::Pari` installed somewhere else, obscuring the failure.  What does %INC hold for you?

Comment: Since `Math::Pari` seems to include compiled code (even assembler), check your and your client’s machine have identical architectures (possibly even down to the libc and compiler).

Comment: Hi all
@chrsblck -  I've rewritten the update to in order to clarify thing.

Comment: @pilcrow how can I check if theres another installation of Math::Pari? can you elaborate about it & about %INC

Comment: @StefanPaletta  the architectures are probably not identical, there is no way I will be able to use this library independent of the environment?

Comment: @GalMazor, please see [perlvar's section on %INC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40INC).

Comment: @pilcrow - % is empty on both machines :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many many CPAN distributions that must go through a build and install process; you cannot just unpack the files from CPAN and point perl at them.

Math::Pari is one; it has to compile bindings to an external library (which also must be present).

You are out of luck with this approach.

Comment: anyone can reassure  @ysth answer?

Comment: @GalMazor: what ysth has says is true.

Comment: @GalMazor: if you have a machine with each architecture you intend to support, you can install everything you need and bundle it up with pp (http://p3rl.org/pp)

Comment: (though even that I think won't include the actual pari library)

Comment: @ysth , I'ts need to be supported on many deployments so it's not so practical... 

I've accepted your answer, but I cant upvote you sinc my rep is under 15 - if someone sees this -> upvote ysth :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to switch to [Net::OpenSSH::Compat::Perl](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH%3a%3aCompat%3a%3aPerl) that is compatible at the API level with most of Net::SSH::Perl and has less and easier to install dependencies.

Its only non-pure Perl dependencies are [IO::Pty](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aPty) required in order to support password authentication and the OpenSSH `ssh` binary that will be already installed on the machine for Linux and BSD systems or available as a package for Solaris and probably several other unixen.