# Problems with using SFTP perl module

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use the SFTP module in Perl. My code looks likes this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl5 

use lib "/some_path/Net-SFTP-0.10/lib";
use lib "/some_path/Net-SSH-Perl-1.25/lib";
use lib "/some_path/Math-Pari-2.010709";

use Net::SFTP;
```

I get this error when running it:

```
Can't locate Math/Pari.pm in @INC
```

The Math-Pari-2.010709 directory contains the Pari.pm.  I do not have permission to make a Math directory and put the Pari.pm file there.  What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you really sure you don't want to install your modules properly? I see `Math::Pari` includes some `.xs` files, so a compilation step would seem beneficial.

Comment: This should sum it up for you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423392/perl-cant-locate-loadable-object-for-module-mathpari-in-inc).

Comment: I take that you don't have control over this system. Is this a server? Can you get your IT department to install NET::SFTP and Net::SSH for you? Also, take a look at [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.75/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm) and [Net::SFTP::Foreign::Compat](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.75/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign/Compat.pm). These might provide everything you need and require fewer modules.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have much control over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `local::lib` and set `$PERL5LIB` to `$HOME/perl5` so building and installing missing modules is fairly easy:

```
% cpanm Math::Pari
--> Working on Math::Pari
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/I/IL/ILYAZ/modules/Math-Pari-2.01080605.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Math-Pari-2.01080605 ... OK
Building and testing Math-Pari-2.01080605 ... 
Successfully installed Math-Pari-2.01080605
1 distribution installed
```

You'll need to install [`App::cpanminus`](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus) by following the instructions at https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus which essentially are:

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

After that with `cpanm` in your `$PATH` (here it is in `$HOME/perl5/bin`) installing modules in your own **$HOME** directory is a breeze.

Comment: Your next step is to start using [```perlbrew```](http://www.perlbrew.pl) and more completely separate your system perl installation from your development environment.

Comment: Be very careful about recommending `perlbrew`, or the OP could be out of a job. If this machine is a production server, installing a second version of Perl could be a violation of the OP's corporate IT policy. I work for large financial institutions, and they have lots of legal requirements they must follow and lots of audits to make sure. An unapproved executable install will cause alarm bells to ring.

Comment: David, point taken but ```perlbrew, cpanm``` and *local to user* - not system level installations - are a way to isolate system level applications from test and development environments on *any* system.  Besides anyone installing perl modules on live production equipment is probably not working on the core IT assets of a bank. If they were, they'd have exact duplicate isolated test environments and would not be installing SFTP (!) from CPAN.

Answer (score 2):

Following the comments, I ended up using [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.75/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm).  It is sufficient to get stuff done, and fewer dependencies made life easier on me.  Thanks for all the help!